# rsync --exclude option for copying folders from server

Tags: rsync

I am trying to backup files from cluster to my local computer. On the process, I am trying to avoid some unnecessary sub-directories from cluster being copied.

So I use `rsync -av user@cluster.com:/home/dir . --exclude user@cluster.com:/home/dir/subdir`, where `subdir` is the folder I am trying to avoid. However, the above option copies all files and folders including `subdir`. How to exclude `subdir`?

Comment: @Arronical: True. The `exclude` folder must be relative to the `source` directory and not the absolute path.

Comment: It works! I was putting it up as answer. But I would leave this for you....

Comment: Yes. The solution is `rsync -av user@cluster.com:/home/dir . --exclude subdir`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the path that you hand to `--exclude` should be relative to the original source path of the `rsync` command. This also means that you can do away with the `/` at the beginning of `/subdir`

Also there's no need to specify the user and host in the `--exclude` part.

So the correct command would be:

```
rsync -av user@cluster.com:/home/dir . --exclude subdir
```

Note that `rsync --exclude` can also do pattern matching, and the `--exclude-from` option is a great way to use a file listing multiple exclude patterns if you have more complicated exclusions.